# Error: Dynamically fetching css from CDN with fallback to local copy, How to resolve?

Tags: php, css, function, external

I had asked this question earlier also but since I did not get a resolvable solution, I am asking this again. I am trying to fetch my CSS from external CDN service let's say `http://cdn.example.com/`.

This code is suppose to check if file exists on external CDN and if it does, then get that file else get it from a local folder.

Please help me correct this code.

```
function getCSSfile($filename)
{
    $externalcss = EXTERNAL_CDN.'css/'.$filename.'.css';
    $localcss = LOCAL_CDN.'css/'.$filename.'.css';

    $ctx = stream_context_create(array(
        'http' => array(
            'method' => 'HEAD'
        )
    ));

    if (file_get_contents($externalcss, false, $ctx) !== false) {
        echo '<link href="' . $externalcss . '" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all"/>';
    } else if (file_exists($localcss)) {
        echo '<link href="' . $localcss . '" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all"/>';
    } else {
        echo 'Error loading CSS File'; 
    }
}
```

Currently code runs fine it fetches the copy from external CDN and if the external CDN is unavailable it does fetches the local copy **BUT** throws the following error too:

`Warning: file_get_contents(http://cdn.site1.com/css/core.css): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found in D:\xampp\htdocs\site2\core\core.php on line 165`

and in line 165 this is the code

`if (file_get_contents($externalcss, false, $ctx) !== false) {`

I am testing it locally and created some domains on my XAMPP Server, hence cannot share a live link.

Comment: You're going to **destroy** the benefits of having a CDN by doing a remote `file_get_contents` on every pageview... Plus, this won't really detect CDN outages, as any good CDN is going to have dozens of datacenters all over the world - you'd only be detecting outages in one or two of those datacenters. Finally, if you need this, *get a better CDN that isn't down all the time!*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in [the docs](http://php.net/file_get_contents), `file_get_contents()` will throw a warning if the stated resource cannot be found.

This is one of the few cases in which using the `@` error suppression operator may be justified, e.g.

```
if (@file_get_contents(...) !== FALSE) { ... }
```

to prevent the warning from mucking up your output.